# Add Button on custom View in Android

Tags: android, button, view

I have the following class

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      View gameView = new GameView(this);
      setContentView(gameView);
   }
}
```

and now I'd like to add a Button to my class GameView.

```
public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
// Code ...
}
```

I need this button during my game, so it should be alywas in front of all the other canvas' I'm drawing.
 How can I do that?

Comment: Where is your button? in the activity or you want to create a new one?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to create a new button?

```
Button b = new Button(context);
b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                   LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 

gameView.addView(b);
```

Use `ViewGroup` as `GameView` parent insted of simple View

```
ViewGroup gameView = new GameView(this);


public class GameView extends ViewGroup { //...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
View gameView = new GameView(this);
```

replace the above line by below line::

```
View gameView = new GameView(this).createView();
```

and now in the Game view createview with button and etc.

```
    public class GameView extends View {
    private Activity _activity;
    public GameView (Activity _activity) {
        super(_activity);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this._activity = _activity; 
    }
public View createView(){
        LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(_activity);
        l.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        Button btn = new Button(_activity);
        btn.setId(1);
            btn.setText("btn"+(i+1));
        l.addView(btn);
        return l;
    }
}
```

try this working code:::