# How to add a button to a custom view?

Tags: java, android

I'm going too build a painting application with some buttons. Now i want to add some buttons to that. my code as follows.

```
 package com.example.drawing;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;


    public class TouchActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new SingleTouchEventView(this, null));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_touch, menu);
        return true;
    }
    }


package com.example.drawing;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class SingleTouchEventView extends View {
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Path path = new Path();

    public SingleTouchEventView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(6f);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // nothing to do
            break;
        default:
            return false;
        }

        // Schedules a repaint.
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

How can i add a button to this?.  reffered some sites and some answers to questions in Stackoverflow ([link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014780/add-button-on-custom-view-in-android) [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504243/add-a-button-to-view)) But couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Could you put that custom view in a RelativeLayout and add the buttons there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class GraphicsActivity like:

```
class GraphicsActivity extends Activity {

private static final boolean TEST_PICTURE = true;
int f=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


}



@Override
public void setContentView(View view) {
    if (TEST_PICTURE) {

        if(f==0){
        ViewGroup vg = new PictureLayout(this);
        vg.addView(view);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, vg);
        view = vg;
        }

    }



    super.setContentView(view);
}



/*@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if(newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        f=0;
        }else{
         f=1;


        }

}*/
```

}

Create your `activity_main` and add necessary buttons on it.
The following is your `PictureLayout.java`:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Picture;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewParent;

class PictureLayout extends ViewGroup {
    private final Picture mPicture = new Picture();

    public PictureLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public PictureLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child) {
        if (getChildCount() > 1) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "PictureLayout can host only one direct child");
        }

        super.addView(child);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index) {
        if (getChildCount() > 1) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "PictureLayout can host only one direct child");
        }

        super.addView(child, index);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, LayoutParams params) {
        if (getChildCount() > 1) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "PictureLayout can host only one direct child");
        }

        super.addView(child, params);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index, LayoutParams params) {
        if (getChildCount() > 1) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "PictureLayout can host only one direct child");
        }

        super.addView(child, index, params);
    }

    @Override
    protected LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
        return new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final int count = getChildCount();

        int maxHeight = 0;
        int maxWidth = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
                measureChild(child, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            }
        }

        maxWidth += getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
        maxHeight += getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();

        Drawable drawable = getBackground();
        if (drawable != null) {
            maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, drawable.getMinimumHeight());
            maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, drawable.getMinimumWidth());
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(resolveSize(maxWidth, widthMeasureSpec),
                resolveSize(maxHeight, heightMeasureSpec));
    }

    private void drawPict(Canvas canvas, int x, int y, int w, int h, float sx,
            float sy) {
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(x, y);
        canvas.clipRect(0, 0, w, h);
        canvas.scale(0.5f, 0.5f);
        canvas.scale(sx, sy, w, h);
        canvas.drawPicture(mPicture);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(mPicture.beginRecording(getWidth(), getHeight()));
        mPicture.endRecording();

        int x = getWidth() / 2;
        int y = getHeight() / 2;

        if (true) {
            canvas.drawPicture(mPicture);
        } else {
            drawPict(canvas, 0, 0, x, y, 1, 1);
            //drawPict(canvas, x, 0, x, y, -1, 1);
            //drawPict(canvas, 0, y, x, y, 1, -1);
            //drawPict(canvas, x, y, x, y, -1, -1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewParent invalidateChildInParent(int[] location, Rect dirty) {
        location[0] = getLeft();
        location[1] = getTop();
        dirty.set(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        return getParent();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        final int count = super.getChildCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
                final int childLeft = getPaddingLeft();
                final int childTop = getPaddingTop();
                child.layout(childLeft, childTop,
                        childLeft + child.getMeasuredWidth(),
                        childTop + child.getMeasuredHeight());

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above procedure should work.Your class should extend `GraphicsActivity` instead of `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button programmatically or your custom view can inflate an xml. You add to this xml the buttons you want and you are still able to draw on the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You just needed to extend ViewGroup rather than View for your custom view to add some child to it and add button to it dynamically as

```
SingleTouchEventView view = new SingleTouchEventView(this, null);

Button btn = new Button(this);
LayoutParams pars = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
btn.setLayoutParams(pars);
btn.setText("Hello World");
btn.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
view.addView(btn);

setContentView(view);
```